# Neo4j CQL: For each node, return oldest related node X

Tags: foreach, cypher

I have something like `(p:Post)-[:USED]->[e:Email] RETURN e.address, p.createdAt` that would return:

[image: sample results screenshot]

I'm trying to get only the oldest `p.createdAt` for each unique email address.
For the above example, it'd be:

[image: desired results screenshot]

Additionally, I'd like to know just how old that post is in number of months.

[image: desired results with months]

I currently have this query but it's just returning all the posts and all the post ages:

```
MATCH (p:Post)-[:USED_EMAIL]->(e:Email)
WITH p, e.address AS email
  ORDER BY p.createdAt ASC
WITH email, COLLECT(p.createdAt) AS collection
WITH email, collection[0] AS oldestPost, duration.inMonths(datetime(collection[0]), datetime()) AS durationMonths
WITH email, oldestPost, durationMonths.months AS numMonthsAgo
RETURN email, oldestPost, numMonthsAgo
```

Please help. I'm getting completely turned around trying to figure this out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
MATCH (p:Post)-[:USED_EMAIL]->(e:Email)
WITH p, e.address as email
  ORDER BY p.createdAt ASC
WITH email, collect(p.createdAt)[0] as first_post
RETURN email, first_post, duration.inMonths(datetime(collection[0]), datetime()).months AS durationMonths
```

Comment: Thanks @tomaž-bratanič! This worked great (with minor tweak, see below)!

`MATCH (p:Post)-[:USED_EMAIL]->(e:Email)
WITH p, e.address AS email
  ORDER BY p.createdAt ASC
WITH email, COLLECT(p.createdAt)[0] AS collection
RETURN email, collection, duration.inMonths(datetime(collection), datetime()).months AS durationMonths`